# Jtable dynamical fixed columns problems

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a class that can dynamically to lock and unlock columns . 
In my program i create two tables with the same tablemodel.
One is in the Jviewport of the scrollpane, the other in the RowHeaderView. 
The problem is when you unlock all the locked columns 
and you want to start to lock again, doesn't work. There are no errors but it's like the event doesn't answer.

Steps to produce the problem:

1. Try the code,
2. put all the columns in the fixed table,
3. then unlock with right double click,
4. then start again to lock, and unlock

Do this procedure and you can see that the mouse event doesnt answer anymore

```
public class Prova extends JFrame{

private JTable mainTable,fixedTable;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTableHeader mainTableHeader;
private TableColumnModel originalColumnModel,mainColumnModel,fixedColumnModel;
private TableColumn[] columns;
private int ncols,counter;

public Prova(){

    counter = 0;
    TableModel mainTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(5, 10);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    mainTable = new JTable(mainTableModel);
    mainColumnModel = mainTable.getColumnModel();

    fixedTable = new JTable();
    fixedTable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
    fixedTable.setModel(mainTable.getModel() );

    ncols = mainTableModel.getColumnCount();
    columns = new TableColumn[ncols];
    for (int i=0;i<ncols;i++){
        columns[i] = mainColumnModel.getColumn(i);
    }

    mainColumnModel = mainTable.getColumnModel();
    fixedColumnModel = fixedTable.getColumnModel();
    mainTableHeader = mainTable.getTableHeader();

    mainTableHeader.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
            if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)){
                if (ncols - counter>1){
                    counter ++;
                    int col = mainTable.columnAtPoint(me.getPoint());
                    TableColumn column = mainColumnModel.getColumn(col);
                    mainColumnModel.removeColumn(column);
                    fixedTable.getColumnModel().addColumn(column);
                    scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(fixedTable);
                    scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, fixedTable.getTableHeader());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    fixedTable.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
            if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me) && me.getClickCount()== 2 ){

                while (mainColumnModel.getColumnCount() > 0){
                    mainColumnModel.removeColumn(mainColumnModel.getColumn(0));
                }

                while (fixedColumnModel.getColumnCount() > 0){
                    fixedColumnModel.removeColumn(fixedColumnModel.getColumn(0));
                }

                for(int i=0;i<ncols;i++){
                    mainColumnModel.addColumn(columns[i]);
                }

                scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(null); 
            }

        }
    });

    scrollPane.setViewportView(mainTable);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
        public void run() {
    new Prova().setVisible(true);
        }
});
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Additionally, try to minimize your example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - it helps readability and that helps in giving a relevant answer

Comment: It would be good to Check the LINk provided by adam

Comment: `Now its all shorter` - no that code is worse because we can't execute the code so we can't see what the problem is. There is no way anybody could solve the problem based on that code. You need to post a proper `SSCCE` when asking a question. You are lucky I saw the old code. Read my answer for tips on creating a better SSCCE along with the answer to your question (as I understand the question anyway).

Comment: `you can see that the mouse event doesnt answer anymore` - how do you know the mouse event doesn't answer? Does the event not answer, or does the code in the event not get executed? Did you add any debug code to the mouse event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few pointers when posting a SSCCE:

```
for (int i=0;i<ncols;i++){
```

Don't be afraid to use whitespace in you code to make it more readable be separating the 3 statements of the for statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ncols; i++){
```

Keep the code simple and directly related to the problem:

```
TableModel mainTableModel = new EmployeeTableModel(listEmployees);
```

You question is about "moving columns", not about the data in the table so there is no need for a special TableModel and the Employee class. Just use the DefaultTableModel:

```
TableModel mainTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(5, 10);
```

Your current code won't compile because you didn't include the Employee class. By using JDK classes the code is smaller and easier to read.

> The problem is when you unlock all the locked columns and you want to start to lock again, doesnt work

Your looping code is wrong. I didn't bother to figure out what was wrong. Instead I made the code simpler:

```
//for(int i=0;i<(ncols-counter);i++){
while (mainColumnModel.getColumnCount() > 0)
{
    mainColumnModel.removeColumn(mainColumnModel.getColumn(0));
}

//for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
while (fixedColumnModel.getColumnCount() > 0)
{
    fixedColumnModel.removeColumn(fixedColumnModel.getColumn(0));
}
```

Another problem is your fixed table doesn't have a header so you don't know what the columns are. This is fixed by using:

```
scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(fixedTable);
scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, fixedTable.getTableHeader());
```

Now that you have a header you need to add the MouseListener to the header, not the scrollpane:

```
//scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
fixedTable.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

Edit:

You have a similar problem to what I fixed above. That is don't keep using variable to track values when you can use the component itself.

```
if (ncols - counter>1){
```

You never reset the value of the counter so the if condition won't be true the second time.

As I did above just use the value from the column model:

```
//if (ncols - counter>1){
if (mainColumnModel.getColumnCount() > 1) {
```

This is just basic problem solving. Put a display statement in the block of code to see if it executes when you have problems.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Post a proper SSCCE with the changes I suggested. It worked fine for me.

Comment: You didn't change the "for loops". I was getting an Exception using your code. That is why I simplified the code and posted my solution.

Comment: `i didnt cause your loops dont work` - that statement means nothing to me. I don't know what you mean by "didn't work". As far as I am concerned it works fine. When you double click the columns are removed from the fixed table and the main table now contains all the columns. I don't know what else you expect to happen??? Describe in detail the steps you do to cause a problem. Put that information in the question, not in a comment here.

Comment: @Camrick i would a suggestion from you. do you think the way how i ve done the program is the best way to do what i need?

Comment: I would create code that is more reusable. For example check out [Fixed Table Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/) for code that is similar to yours. I haven't tried it but you can probably specify 0 for the number of fixed columns. Then you would modify the code to add the functionality of the MouseListeners to dynamically add/remove columns.

Comment: i saw quickly that code, but in that code is the programmer that decides how many fixed column, in my program is the operator that blocks dinamically the columns. the only point where i'm not sure it is the best way is how i unlock columns and reset the tables, there is another way better than mine , more speedy and more directly? i dont want the you write code , just if you have another idea to reset the table ( i tryed to create a new table model and set it to the main table, it works but i dont prefer this way)